# Can two different computers on the same home network have different public IP addresses via different ISPs?

Tags: networking, internet, ip-address, isp

Comcast provides Internet service for my home network and I noticed last night that my public IP address had changed using [WhatsMyIp.org](https://whatsmyip.org). The "Hostname & User Agent" ended with the domain "myvzw.com" which I thought was strange because that looked like a Verizon owned site and my Internet is provided by Comcast.

I know that an ISP can change my public IP address but when I looked at a different computer on the same home network, it still showed the original IP address and the ISP domain ended with "comcast.net" which is what I expected.

Both computers are Apple (2019 MacBook Pro running Mojave - this showed the "new" public IP address, and 2020 iMac running Catalina). Both are hardwired (no wireless tethering to my Verizon iPhone 11). Cable modem is Cisco DPC3008 and Router is Google Wi-Fi. DNS Automatic is 8.8.8.8 (Google) and ISP is 75.75.75.75 (Comcast).

I've read about Carrier-grade NAT - is this a possibility and if so, would it cross between Comcast and Verizon?

After rebooting the Mac with the "new" public IP address, it reverted to the "original" address but I thought it would be worth asking here. I ran a Norton Security scan for what its worth and nothing specific was detected.

My biggest concern is that my computer was hacked in some way (IP hijacking via BGP? Man in the middle attack?) but thought I would ask the experts here.

Comment: This sort of thing becomes very hard to investigate after it has gone away -- there are many things I'm no longer able to ask you to check. Are you using any VPN services at all? Are there any other wired or wireless devices on your network?

Comment: “I've read about Carrier-grade NAT - is this a possibility and if so, would it cross between Comcast and Verizon?” - Comcast and Verizon are competitors this absolutely would never happen. “My biggest concern is that my computer was hacked in some way (IP hijacking via BGP?” - This also didn’t happen.  You are also not a victim of a man in the middle attack

Comment: I am not using VPN services. Yes, there are other computers on my home network - both wired (computers) and wireless (iOS devices).